# Remove variable parts of an input list

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have an input list from which I want to remove occurrences of a variable string. Say my input list looks as follows:

```
(BLA-123) some text
BLA-123 some text
BLA-123: some text
some text (BLA-123)
some text BLA-123
```

I would like my input list to look like:

```
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
```

Basically, I need to remove all occurrences of any `BLA-[0-9]{1,4}` which may be inclosed in `(` and `)` or followed by a `:`, both from the beginning and the end of any line in the input list.

I thought of using `cut` but is kind of hard to achieve what I need. Then I thought of `sed`, which I believe is the way to go, but I have little to none experience with it.

Comment: The last line does not contain `()` nor a `:`. How to handle this?

Comment: I wrote that it _may_ be enclosed or followed by, it doesn't necessarily have to be.

Comment: Sorry, but then it might be impossible to answer. You know that it requires a pattern replacement. If no pattern can be named, then pattern replacement can't be used

Comment: Why? Isn't it possible to replace the occurrences of some string only if it exists? It doesn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
sed 's/ *[(]*[A-Z][A-Z]*-[0-9]\{1,4\}[):]* *//'
```

I've replace `BLA` with an arbitrary upper-case string `[A-Z][A-Z]*` because I don't know whether you meant it as a meta-variable in the problem description.

If you have the GNU `sed`, this can be slightly improved by using `\?` and `\+`:

```
sed 's/ *[(]\?[A-Z]\+-[0-9]\{1,4\}[):]\? *//'
```

These, however, convert:

```
some text BLA-123 more text
```

to:

```
some textmore text
```

which may not be what you want. If you want such a line to remain unchanged, then you can double the substitution, modifying the first so that it matches only at the start, and the second so it matches at the end:

```
sed 's/^ *[(]\?[A-Z]\+-[0-9]\{1,4\}[):]\? *//;s/ *[(]\?[A-Z]\+-[0-9]\{1,4\}[):]\? *$//'
```

Comment: I've gone with this variant. Thanks for your detailed answer and for all the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very optimal... but works:

```
$ sed -e 's/(BLA-[0-9]*)[ ]*//g' -e 's/BLA-[0-9]*:[ ]*//g' -e 's/BLA-[0-9]*[ ]*//g' a
some text
some text
some text
some text 
some text
```

- `s/(BLA-[0-9]*)[ ]*//g` deletes `(BLA-XXXX)` plus eventual trailing spaces.
- `s/BLA-[0-9]*:[ ]*//g` deletes `BLA-XXXX:` plus eventual trailing spaces.
- `s/BLA-[0-9]*[ ]*//g` deletes `BLA-XXXX` plus eventual trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
sed -E 's/[[:punct:]]?BLA-[[:digit:]]{1,4}[[:punct:]]?[[:space:]]*//'
```

There's a trailing space at the end of some output lines that you can eliminate by putting `[[:space:]]*` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ *(BLA-[0-9]\{1,4\}) *//
s/ *BLA-[0-9]\{1,4\}:\{0,1\} *//' YourFile
```

avoid the opening `(` without cloing `)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk one-liner:

```
$ cat toto
(BLA-123) some text
BLA-123 some text
BLA-123: some text
some text (BLA-123)
some text BLA-123

$ awk '{for (i=0;i<=NF;i=i+1) if ($i!~/BLA/) printf $i" "}{printf "\n"}' toto
some text 
some text 
some text 
some text 
some text
```

Which can be translated by

for each line (awk works by parsing line by line), for each field (NF is Number of Field, ie column), is the column number `i` does not contain BLA you print it. After each line, print `"\n"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Add what's the delimiter used to split the line into columns?

Comment: @AndreiHorak The default delimiter is a space or tab. If you want to change it add :
awk -F":" '{for (i=0;i<=NF;i=i+1) if ($i!~/BLA/) printf $i" "}{printf "\n"}' toto
And now, it will define the column as being before or after ":". So in your example, the number of field will be respectively : 1,1,2,1,1